# Java complains that identifier is expected

Tags: java

I am having a very strange problem with myc code here. I have a simple program with 6 classes, that worked just yesterday and it won't work today. I didn't write anything extra to the class, but it complains about two parameters I have put in two methods. Interesting thing is, that parameter in the switch method is ok there, but it does not like when I put that in the parameters. Also, when I delete them - there is another error upcoming, so it needs to have it. I am talking about parameter `cmd` here. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
public class Menu {

    private Login login;

    public Menu() {
        this.login = new Login();         
        this.displayMenu();
        this.runProgram();
    }

    private void runProgram() {

        boolean running = true;
        Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in );

        while(running) {

            if (this.login.loggedIn) {
                Movies movies = new Movies();
                movies.run();
            } else {
                this.mainMenu(in.nextInt());
            }  
        }
    }


    private void movieMenu(cmd) {

    }

    private void mainMenu(cmd) {
        switch (cmd) {
            case 1:
                this.login();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println ( "Program terminates" );
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 3:
                this.register();
                break;
            case 4:
                this.findUser();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the errors pls

Comment: In private void mainMenu(cmd)  what is type of cmd ?

Comment: Menu.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
   private void movieMenu(cmd) {
                             ^
Menu.java:42: error: <identifier> expected
   private void mainMenu(cmd) {
                            ^
2 errors

Comment: *"that worked just yesterday"* - Not with those syntax errors it didn't.  Your assumptions are patently false.

Comment: `mainMenu(int cmd)`. You're missing the type of `cmd`

Comment: The Menu constructor is calling this.displayMenu(); and it's not defined?

Comment: cmd was just a parameter, I havent declared it before. Funny thing is, that I tried it at another computer and it worked, but when we deleted cmd and wrote that again it stopped working

Comment: The syntax is ok, its just me who posted the code incorretly I guess

Comment: I tried to give it a type, both String and int, but it just wont work

Comment: @LorneMalvo: The code you're showing us is clearly a syntax error, so that's the problem.  You forgot the type specifier for the method parameter.  If you have *some other code* that's giving *some other error* then demonstrate that.  "I tried some stuff and it doesn't work" isn't something we can help with.

Comment: I am sorry,  this was my first qustion, next time I will try to be more specific, but solution is found, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void movieMenu(cmd)
                  ^^^ int cmd
```

You need to the specify the type for `cmd` in the method parameter.